# Keep session alive after closing browser.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

How can i do, that after user add something to shopping cart, and leave browser (close) after reopening rails recover it's session, and user can shop more...
Now I have such

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :current_cart 
  private
    def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end


end
```

And destroying after making order:

```
def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @cart.destroy
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to session[:prev_url],
        :notice => I18n.t(:empty_card) }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

But how can i tell RoR to keep this session alive?

Comment: You need to preserve your session cookie, but that's generally not a good idea to do. Use cookies-based technique instead.

Comment: @semir.babajic will i have most functionality as before, if i change for example session[:cart_id] = cart.id to cookies[:cart_id] = cart.id ? how then can i restore my cart?

Comment: Keep a copy of the cart in your database with a reference to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store `cart_id` into cookies instead of session, and you'll achieve what you want. When you need to pull out cart information, use the ID from cookies.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :current_cart 
  private
    def current_cart
      Cart.find(cookies[:cart_id])
      @cart = Cart.find(cookies[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      cookies[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end


end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly. Keep in mind to set the appropriate cookie duration, you don't want it to last forever, nor too short.

Comment: cookie[:..... or cookies[:... is right?  Also where i need to write duration, in appcontroller?

Comment: cookies[:] is right, see my updated comment. This is how you set duration: 'cookies[:cart_id] = { :value => "XYZ", :expires => 5.hour.from_now }'